# get_started + Banner image on facebook messenger chatbot

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I want to display Get Started button with banner image as per shown in image.
I know how to show get_started button but facing issue with Banner image with greet text.
[image]

Need help for achieving this. I tried with below request but no success.
For displaying get-started I used,

```
{
  "setting_type" : "call_to_actions",
  "thread_state" : "new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "payload":"USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
    }
  ]
}
```

But not getting how to set banner image with this request. Also I tried with,

```
{
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"image", 
      "payload":{
        "is_reusable": true,
        "url":"url"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In response getting "attachment_id" but not getting where to use it. Please help on this.
Added the chatbot welcome screen screenshot for reference.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Images seen on the example `Get Started` page you posted are coming from `Facebook Page`'s profile picture and cover photo.

There doesn't seem to be an option in the API to attach a different image to `Get Started` today.

To get the "banner" show up, add a cover photo to your Facebook Page.

Comment: Thanks dear for clearing my doubt. I was thinking the same but no reference found for that so posted the question. But on GetStarted facebook cover pic not coming for my bot? Anymore cases for the same?